# Docker start with configured ports

Tags: docker, xampp, docker-container

I have problem with Docker. I created new container using `﻿sudo docker run --name myXampp -p 41061:22 -p 41062:80 -d -v ~/Projekty/Xampp:/www pindr0p/xampp` and I could access localhost:41062, but when i restarted my pc, i wanted to run docker container and again access server so I did `sudo docker start myXampp` but I can not access localhost:41062 anymore. Did I miss something? I even tried start with -p flags, but no success. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try following again
`sudo docker run --name myXampp -p 41061:22 -p 41062:80 -d -v ~/Projekty/Xampp:/www pindr0p/xampp`

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/myXampp" is already in use by container "29ddc6836adfa14d4ec3a025fddd2e5587212fef77ba0d6edb83642a3daedd3e". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Comment: that means even you restarted your container is up and running.

Comment: but I can not access server

Comment: what is the error you get when you try to access localhost:41062?
Btw I think you need to execute the full command rather than `sudo docker start myXampp` after restart

Comment: Accessing via chrome: GET http://localhost:41062/phpmyadmin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: As I know docker containers not restart when you restart your pc or server. We have to restart the containers again.
Suggestion- just stop and remove the container and restart your machine and run again `sudo docker run --name myXampp -p 41061:22 -p 41062:80 -d -v ~/Projekty/Xampp:/www pindr0p/xampp`

Answer (score 0):

**Restart your container by container Id**

List all the containers who are existed or check the status of your containers after restart

```
docker ps -a
```

Then restart the container by Contaner Id

```
docker restart <container_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove it competently

first please get list of dockers run as process

```
docker ps
```

then try to remove it:

```
docker rm <your-docker> --force
```

then try to run

```
docker ps
```

and make sure the docker removed
then try to

docker run blob

again

yes the container made from image again and all your new config reverted back

Comment: This works great if you want to blow away any database you created and loaded. What can be done if you want to persist the data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the container using:

```
sudo docker stop 29ddc6836adfa14d4ec3a025fddd2e5587212fef77ba0d6edb83642a3daedd3e
```

and then try:

```
sudo docker run --name myXampp -p 41061:22 -p 41062:80 -d -v ~/Projekty/Xampp:/www pindr0p/xampp
```